# How to aggregate in R where the values become the column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm fairly new to R and using the dplyr package currently. I have a dataframe that looks something like this simplified table:

| year | category |
| --- | --- |
| 2009 | A |
| 2009 | B |
| 2009 | B |
| 2010 | A |
| 2010 | B |
| 2011 | A |
| 2011 | C |
| 2011 | C |

I want to count for each year hence I used:

```
df %>% count(year, category)
```

and got

| year | category | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | A | 1 |
| 2009 | B | 2 |
| 2010 | A | 1 |
| 2010 | B | 1 |
| 2011 | A | 1 |
| 2011 | C | 2 |

However I would like to use the year as column names, to get the following:

|  | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 2 |

What is an easy way to get this? I would like to get this in absolute numbers, and if possible as a normalized table (percentages of the total of each year).

I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: `table(rev(df))`

Comment: This was not possible as i'm using a larger df with 50+ columns not only the two columns I showed here.

Comment: # If happy with a cross-tab:
`xtabs(cnt~category+year, transform(df, cnt = 1))`

# If requring a data.frame:
`as.data.frame.matrix(
  xtabs(cnt~category+year, transform(df, cnt = 1))
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reshape`:

```
df2 = df %>% count(year, category)

df2 = reshape(df2, idvar='category', timevar='year', direction='wide')

rownames(df2) = df2$category

df2[is.na(df2)] = 0

df2 = df2[,c(2:4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>% count(year, category) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    category,
    names_from = year,
    names_prefix = "year_",
    values_from = n, 
    values_fill = 0
  )


# A tibble: 3 x 4
  category year_2009 year_2010 year_2011
  <chr>        <int>     <int>     <int>
1 A                1         1         1
2 B                2         1         0
3 C                0         0         2
```